# Hierarchy viewer is giving better numbers in emulator than my real device(xperia arc)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

i have this layout for my news app

```
<ScrollView >
 <RealativeLayout>
  <TextView/>
 <HorizontalListView> //a custom View that uses baseadapter and view recycling
  <ReativeLayout/>
   <ImageView/>
   <TextView/>
  <ReativeLayout/>
  <ReativeLayout/>
   <ImageView/>
   <TextView/>
  <ReativeLayout/>
   <ReativeLayout/>
   <ImageView/>
   <TextView/>
  <ReativeLayout/>
 <HorizontalListView/>
      .
      .
      five horizontal srollViews
```

The problem is that on my xperia arc (my debugging device)
The Scroll View is very laggy , and the hierarchy viewer shows high numbers of draw time on all views
while when i debug on a galaxy s3 specs emulator , the app on the emulator is far more smooth and hirarchy viewer gives much better draw layout and measure numbers.
is it normal that the emulator gets faster number on the emulator? oris something with the phone, or it is the code:

Notes : my xperia arc has CM9 
all images in the layout are downloaded in a separate thread and put into a Lrucache.

the HorizontalscreenView onlayout() method create a new runnable object every time onlayout is 
called(so that i can request layout while scrolling to recycle views)

Comment: i discovered that removing the alpha property from the text views displaying news titles, the performance improved greatly.
i had a layout similar to the bbc news app but instead of having textview with compunddrawable i wnted to overlay the textview at the bottom half of the image, didn't know that opacity causes such a performance hit, looks like the emulator ignores alpha property all together , or because the emulator had 1024mb ram vs 384 on xperia arc. i will investigate more may be it's totally something else. i had about 15 news articles in my layou i suppose that was much for a  mob